# How to hold on an element in a LinkedBlockingQueue?

Tags: java, queue, delay

I am using a `LinkedBlockingQueue` in java and I want to hold an element in the queue before release it to the thread. In other words, I want to set up a delay before having an element out of the queue.

```
private LinkedBlockingQueue<String> testQue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>()
if ( position.equals("leader") ) {
   //process this element as the last one
```

Is it possible to do?

Comment: it is not clear to me what you want to achieve. Could you explain the task in a bit more detail?

Comment: If I understand your correctly, you want to delay the processing of an element that is available in the queue? Why would you want to do that? Maybe what you are doing is looking at the problem with the wrong perspective. If you explain what you are trying to achieve, maybe someone can help you better

Comment: I am trying to use a queue instead of using Thread.sleep to create a delay for specific element in the queue. In other words, if an element in the queue is "leader", I want to delay or wait for 1 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the documentation for LinkedBlockingQueue: [https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html](http://LinkedBlockingQueue)

> E peek() Retrieves, but does not remove, the head of this queue, or returns null if this queue is empty.
>
> E poll() Retrieves and removes the head of this queue, or returns null if this queue is empty.
>
> E poll(long timeout, TimeUnit unit) Retrieves and removes the head of this queue, waiting up to the specified wait time if necessary for an   element to become available.

You have two options:

1. Use `peek()` process the element and use a `pool()` when you are done. You may also put a `Thread.sleep(time)` between `peek()` and `pool()` if you really want to wait until it is done.
2. Use `poll(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)` if you now how long is going to take to process the element.